# Why is the second equality wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

Here's a "proof" of $e^x=1$ for all $x$: $$\exp(x)=\exp\left(i2π⋅\frac{x}{i2π}\right)=\bigl(\exp(i2π)\bigr)^{x/(i2π)}=1^{x/(i2π)}=1$$ Why is the second equality wrong?

Comment: Don't post *again* the same question: edit the former one...and use LaTeX!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone tell me why the second equality is wrong?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358615/can-someone-tell-me-why-the-second-equality-is-wrong)

Comment: The "double power" rule for exponents does not hold true for complex expressions, just like there are more rules from real algebra that do not "copy" to algebra involving complex numbers

Comment: @DonAntonio this one makes slightly more sense

Comment: To best understand the explanation (and to get the best answers), it would be useful to *first* explain why you think the second equality is right!

Answer (score 4):

This argument is false because $h(u,v)=u^v$ is not a single-valued function in the complex numbers. In particular, $1^v\neq 1$ for some values of $1^v$.

If you choose some single-valued branch of $u^v$, then it is not true that $\exp(xv)=\exp(x)^v$ in general.

The wonderful, magical thing about $\exp(x)$ is that it is a function - it is well-defined for all complex $x$. But in general exponentiation, we are not so lucky. If $a$ is a complex number, then we usually define $a^x$ to be $\exp(x\ln a)$, but $\ln a$ is not well-defined - there are infinitely many different possible values for $\ln a$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how ln(a) is not well defined for complex number.